# How to limit the number of fileds to be added on a button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I've a code in which I have two buttons, which adds and deletes the form fields. I want to limit the number of adding option to 5.

Here's the code:

```js
function addSite() {
   var new_total_sites = parseInt($('#total_sites').val()) + 1;
   var new_site_label = "<label id='new_label1_" + new_total_sites
                + "'>Additional Research Participation: </label>";
   var new_site_input = "<input id='new_site_"
                + new_total_sites
                + "' type='text' class='form-control' list='sites' name='site[]'></br>";
   var new_slot_label = "<label id='new_label2_" + new_total_sites
                + "'>Research Institution</label>";
   var new_slot_input = "<input class='form-control' id='new_slot_"
                + new_total_sites + "' name='slots[]'></br>";
  var new_research_label = "<label id='new_label3_" + new_total_sites
                + "'>Research Mentor</label>";
   var new_research_input = "<input class='form-control' id='new_research_"
                + new_total_sites + "' name='slots[]'></br>";
var new_form_group_label= "<label class= id='new_label4_" + new_total_sites
                + "'>Type of Research</label>";
   var new_basic_label = "<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox1" + new_total_sites +"' value='basic'><label for='basic' id='basic"+ new_total_sites +"'>Basic</label></br>";
   var new_clinical_label = "<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox2" + new_total_sites +"' value='clinical'><label for='clinical' id='clinical"+ new_total_sites +"'>Clinical</label></br></div>";

   $('#new_site').append(new_site_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_site_input);
   $('#new_site').append(new_slot_label)
   $('#new_site').append(new_slot_input);
   $('#new_site').append(new_research_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_research_input);
   $('#new_site').append(new_form_group_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_basic_label);
   $('#new_site').append(new_clinical_label)

   $('#total_sites').val(new_total_sites)
   }
 function removeSite() {
   var last_total_site = $('#total_sites').val();
   if (last_total_site > 1) {
         $('#new_label1_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_site_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_label2_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_slot_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_label3_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_research_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#new_label4_' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#basic' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#clinical' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#checkbox1' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#checkbox2' + last_total_site).remove('');
         $('#total_sites').val(last_total_site - 1);
   }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=new_site></div>
   
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  onClick="addSite()">Add Mentor</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  onClick="removeSite()">Remove Mentor</button>
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="total_sites">
</br></br>
```

I want to make something where the user should not be able to add the mentor after 5 entries.

Comment: You just need to check how many elements have been added every time you add one, if it's more than a set number then just don't add another one

Comment: The user should be able to add only 5 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way. - I've added the following check to your code:

```
  if ($('#total_sites').val() >= 5) {
    $('button:contains("Add Mentor")').prop('disabled', true);
  }
```

What it does is it checks the value of elements within your `#total_sites` div. If the value is greater than or equal to 5 it will disable the `Add Mentor button`.

I'm disabling the button in this example but you can do something that works for your preference by doing a similar check.

**EDIT:**  To answer the question in your comments, you can add numbered heading by setting a count like this:

```
  var count = $('#total_sites').val();
```

Then include the count in a new element like this:

```
var count = '<h1> Mentor' + count + '</h1>'
```

Finally, append it like the rest of your elements:

```
 $('#new_site').append(count);
```

Run the snippet below to see it in action.

```js
function addSite() {
  var new_total_sites = parseInt($('#total_sites').val()) + 1;
  var count = new_total_sites
  var count = '<h1> Mentor' + count + '</h1>'
  if ($('#total_sites').val() >= 5) {
    $('button:contains("Add Mentor")').prop('disabled', true);
  }
  var new_site_label = "<label id='new_label1_" + new_total_sites + 
    "'>Additional Research Participation: </label>";
  var new_site_input = "<input id='new_site_" +
    new_total_sites +
    "' type='text' class='form-control' list='sites' name='site[]'></br>";
  var new_slot_label = "<label id='new_label2_" + new_total_sites +
    "'>Research Institution</label>";
  var new_slot_input = "<input class='form-control' id='new_slot_" +
    new_total_sites + "' name='slots[]'></br>";
  var new_research_label = "<label id='new_label3_" + new_total_sites +
    "'>Research Mentor</label>";
  var new_research_input = "<input class='form-control' id='new_research_" +
    new_total_sites + "' name='slots[]'></br>";
  var new_form_group_label = "<label class= id='new_label4_" + new_total_sites +
    "'>Type of Research</label>";
  var new_basic_label = "<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox1" + new_total_sites + "' value='basic'><label for='basic' id='basic" + new_total_sites + "'>Basic</label></br>";
  var new_clinical_label = "<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox2" + new_total_sites + "' value='clinical'><label for='clinical' id='clinical" + new_total_sites + "'>Clinical</label></br></div>";
  $('#new_site').append(count);
  $('#new_site').append(new_site_label);
  $('#new_site').append(new_site_input);
  $('#new_site').append(new_slot_label)
  $('#new_site').append(new_slot_input);
  $('#new_site').append(new_research_label);
  $('#new_site').append(new_research_input);
  $('#new_site').append(new_form_group_label);
  $('#new_site').append(new_basic_label);
  $('#new_site').append(new_clinical_label)

  $('#total_sites').val(new_total_sites)
}

function removeSite() {
  var last_total_site = $('#total_sites').val();
  if (last_total_site > 1) {
    $('#new_label1_' + last_total_site).remove('');
    $('#new_site_' + last_total_site).remove('');
    $('#new_label2_' + last_total_site).remove('');
    $('#new_slot_' + last_total_site).remove('');
    $('#new_label3_' + last_total_site).remove('');
    $('#new_research_' + last_total_site).remove('');
    $('#new_label4_' + last_total_site).remove('');
    $('#basic' + last_total_site).remove('');
    $('#clinical' + last_total_site).remove('');
    $('#checkbox1' + last_total_site).remove('');
    $('#checkbox2' + last_total_site).remove('');
    $('#total_sites').val(last_total_site - 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=new_site></div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onClick="addSite()">Add Mentor</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onClick="removeSite()">Remove Mentor</button>
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="total_sites">
</br>
</br>
```

Comment: Hey do you know how to add a heading everytime a new mentor is added like mentor 1, mentor 2, mentor 3 etc?

Comment: Okay that works but how do I start from mentor 2? I already have 1 in the code so I want it to start from 2?

Comment: See the updated code. All I did was change count to this `var count = new_total_sites`.

Comment: Okay thank you so much.
For the backend, should I just make 5 different columns for each mentor?

Comment: To be honest, I can't really say without knowing more about your application. You need to structure your backend in a way that makes sense for your app. - If you think you should store data for each mentor then that's the way you should go. If you're unsure, the best bet would be to create a new question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Okay. I have a form, which each of the field have a separate column in the database. I'll try to create a separate column for each of the five mentors then see if it works. Otherwise will post a new question. Is there a way I can tag you in that?

Comment: Hey I have posted a new question for the backend problem. Can you please check?

Comment: Would love to help but most of my backend work is done with nodeJS. If I was better with PHP I would assist but it's not my area. - Good luck, hope someone can help you out.